# R Shiny - host your own apps?

Tags: r

How can I host my own R Shiny App instead of hosted it at https://www.shinyapps.io?

I run these lines below and my app is uploaded to the server above,

```
> library(shiny)
> library(shinyapps)
> setwd("C:/firstapp")
> deployApp()
```

but we have our own live server that support R, so can we do that?

ps. I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqzHC-xu1S4) and get our app hosted at shinyapps.io but we prefer host it our own. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

The `deployApp()` function only works with shinyapps.io. When running your own installation of shiny server, you will have to take care of deploying and managing your applications manually. This includes installing any required R packages.

To host your own shiny-server, you should get started by downloading shiny-server or shiny-server pro from here: http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

Comment: thanks. that makes sense! Any ideas and guides for `take care of deploying and managing your applications manually. This includes installing any required R packages.`?

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the shiny server from RStudio:

http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

obviously you'll need a machine to host it on if you don't want your desktop getting thrashed.

Comment: yea thanks. but I still don't understand it - when I run `deployApp()` how can my rshiny app knows that it is to be uploaded to my server instead of shinyapps.io?

Comment: It doesn't. You need to copy the shiny app files to a folder on the server. How you do this is dependent on your server - it could be scp, ftp, or a windows share.

Comment: thanks. then how do i copy my app's dependencies to the server? manually (it is impossible I believe)?

Comment: talk to your server admin. if they've installed shiny server for you then they'll be the one to install dependencies, or configure your space on it so you can add them to a personal library. But this is getting off topic (if it ever was on-topic). Ask on the RStudio forums.

Comment: Note you might need *another* server for hosting Shiny apps, not the same one what you are running R on via RStudio Server. Shiny Server is a new service that might need a new hardware server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set-up a shiny server on your personal server if you want to host outside from shinyapps.io

http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

Comment: yea thanks. but I still don't understand it - when I run `deployApp()` how can my rshiny app knows that it is to be uploaded to my server instead of shinyapps.io?